# Issue with updating state using useEffect in portfolio: setIsTop not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm currently working on my portfolio website and I'm trying to update a state variable `isTop` using the `setIsTop` function from the `useState` hook inside a `useEffect` hook. The goal is to change the value of `isTop` based on the user's scroll position. However, the state doesn't seem to be updating as expected.

I've implemented the following code snippet:

```js
const [isTop, setIsTop] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
        const isTop = window.scrollY < 100;
        console.log(isTop); // This doesn't log anything
        setIsTop(isTop); // This doesn't seem to update the state variable
    }

    document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }
}, []);
```

My expectation was that the isTop state would reflect the user's scroll position, allowing me to style the component accordingly. However, the console.log inside the handleScroll function doesn't log anything, and the state update doesn't appear to be functioning as intended.

I've checked if the handleScroll function is being called by adding the console.log, but it doesn't seem to log anything, indicating that the scroll event might not be captured properly.

Could anyone help me understand why the useEffect and useState combination might not be working as expected in this scenario? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code you have given looks ok. Can you add the component where you have this component so we have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Welcome @BadEnd, check this console in this example, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kbk8hb?file=src%2FApp.js Like Youssouf Oumar mentioned the code you provided looks good. If possible share the entire component and possible dependency so we can help you.

Comment: @ChandlerBing

Thank you very much for your help! I have looked at your solution. And thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

But I'm very surprised and funny even though our codes are the same. But mine is not working although before it still works fine.
And now I have switched to another method.

Thanks again!